# Keyboard, trackpad stops functioning on Yosemite when USB smartphone plugged in

Tags: macbook-pro, keyboard, macos

I am using a Retina MacBook Pro 15" Mid 2014 with Mac OS X 10.0 (Yosemite) installed. When I plugin my Android phone via USB, the trackpad and keyboard stop working. Things are still happening on the screen, though, so it's not completely frozen. The only button that works is power button. It happens like 20% of the time I plugin a smartphone. Tried various phones and the issue is still there.

dmesg: http://pastebin.com/sRU5gKTd

Comment: Could you entertain us with a Console log at the time stamp of the event please, so we might see what is going on.

Comment: Try executing `sudo dmesg` in the command line if you see any hints.

Comment: Added dmesg output